# Using \caption for tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I needed to move a picture to the right side of a slide, so I used `tikzpicture`! but with using the `\caption`, it will put the caption right in the middle of the picture.

How can I move the caption?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
  \node [xshift=-2.8cm,yshift=-1cm] at (current page.east)
    {\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Geant_topology.jpg}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Geant Topology}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `overlay` means *don't occupy any space* (roughly speaking).

Comment: You say "slide".  Are you using `beamer` by any chance?  If so, you may as well not use `figure` and simply shove the picture to the side using `\hfill`.

Comment: And do you want text to go to the left of the figure?

Comment: You can include the caption as part of the tikz picture, using a node below the image. Also, as percusse warned, remember that an overlay is superimposed to any other content in the slide, so if you have some text on the left it will "overflow" on the image. Why don't use a two-column layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need Tikz for that, just use two columns.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}       % <-- For dummy images
\usepackage{blindtext} % <-- For dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}

\begin{columns}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \blinditemize
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Geant Topology}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since figures aren't floats in beamer, you can use them within TikZ pictures, so you can add captions and refer to them.

Change the nesting, use figure inside, and there's no problem with overlays when placing. Just remember to compile twice for placing the overlay.

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  See figure \ref{demo}.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
    \node [xshift=-4cm,yshift=-1cm] at (current page.east) {
      \parbox{.5\textwidth}{
        \begin{figure}
          \includegraphics{demo}
          \caption{Demonstration}
          \label{demo}
        \end{figure}
    }};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: frame with figure]